# radio checked and drop down selected to determine URL link to go to

Tags: jquery

I need to choose an option from a dropdown select, then choose a language. Once I have both required fields filled, I should then "open" the desired link, based on what language I had selected.

For example: If I choose english, it will go to URL 1, if I choose french, it will go to URL 2.

How can I get this to check that both required areas are filled before it links anywhere?

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select id="option" required>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="option1"> Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2"> Option 2</option>
    </select>

    <p>Choose a language:</p>
    <label for="en">English</label>
    <input type="radio" name="lang" id="lang-en" value="en" required><br>
    <label for="fr">French</label>
     <input type="radio" name="lang" id="lang-fr" value="fr">

    <input type="submit" id="submit-button" onclick="checkRequired()" value="Open"></input> 

<script>
function checkRequired()
{
if(document.getElementById('lang-en').checked) 
{
window.location="www.url1.com"; 
}
else if(document.getElementById('lang-fr').checked)
{
window.location="www.url2.com";
}
}
</script>           
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the element and do stuff only if it has a value.

You can build an it / else statement like this:

```
if ($('#option').val()) {
  //do stuff
} else {
  //do nothing
}
```

While nothing is selected `$('.option').val()` will return nothing which in this case (Boolean check) returns false. So nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following condition at the start of your function :

```
if($('input[name=lang]:checked').length // checks if either one of the checkboxes are selected
            && 
        $("#option").val() != "") // checks if the value from the select dropdown has been selected
{


}
```

Also, you don't need to explicitly check for selected value to redirect to a certain url. You can use jquery `.data` attributes to redirect directly from the selected option.

```
<select id="option" required>
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="option1"> Option 1</option>
<option value="option2"> Option 2</option>
</select>

<p>Choose a language:</p>
<label for="en">English</label>
<input type="radio" name="lang" id="lang-en" value="en" required data-url="www.url1.com"><br>
<label for="fr">French</label>
 <input type="radio" name="lang" id="lang-fr" value="fr" data-url="www.url2.com">

<input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Open"/>
<script>
$("#submit-button").click(function()
{
   if($('input[name=lang]:checked').length > 0 && $("#option").val() != "")      
    window.location = $('input[name=lang]:checked').eq(0).data('url');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. This checks for the empty dropdown, which is great. Although it doesn't seem to be linking to anything once I hit submit.

Comment: I removed it out of the form tag and it works! However, I am finding if it is a PDF link, it does not download on mobile. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: That might be a different issue altogether and with possible multiple causes. Your best bet would be googling the issue.